# Can't open web page from embedded device when proxy (PAC) is enabled with direct connection

Tags: proxy, embedded, html

I have built  an Embedded device running a web server in it.
I use direct connection to connect my PC and the device (one to one connection).

The embedded device has web pages written using backbone framework.
The device serves web pages and everything works fine in all types of browsers if no proxy is configured.

When Proxy is configured and I try to access the device it fails.
The web page displays "Gateway time out".

I go to settings and disable proxy everything works fine.

Most of the time the proxy will configured at customer's place computes and they face problem when they connect the device directly to PC and try to access the web page (with proxy server being enabled).

Is there a way where I can handle this problem by putting some additional script in my web page so that even with proxy being enabled in the browser the web pages are displayed properly with direct connection.

I tried google search but didn't get any convincing answer.

Kindly support me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you use a proxy in a one-to-one connection?

Comment: No proxy is not used, but some proxy is configured in the PC by default

Answer (score 0):

IE8 change href to absolute when proxy is enabled and not used.
Put below code while parsing URl

```
href.substr(href.indexOf('#')
```

It will solve the problem